# Why does get_transient() always return string even if integer set?

Tags: post-meta, transient

I've been trying to bug fix the following method for hours now, and don't have an idea why it always returns a string, instead of an integer.

The idea is to return a class property, if exists, or a transient value, if the class property doesn't exist (and setting the class property for the next access).

```
public static function get_number( $post_id = null ) {
    // Check if class property already exists
    if ( empty( self::$number ) ) {

        // THIS IS ALWAYS STRING - WHY?
        $number = get_transient( 'my_number' );

        if ( false === $number && $post_id ) {
            $number = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_number', true );

            if ( '' !== $number ) {
                $number = intval( $number );
                // THERE GOES THE INTEGER
                set_transient('my_number', $number, 20 );
            }
        }

        self::$number = $number;
        // Should still be an integer since we've never set any strings to transient
    }

    return self::$number;
}
```

Weird thing is when I call it with a valid `post_id`, I'll get an integer but when calling without, I'll get a string.

So...
`gettype( get_number( 123 ) ) === 'integer'`
`gettype( get_number() ) === 'string'`

**Working Code (based on Otto's answer)**

```
public static function get_number( $post_id = null ) {
    // Check if class property already exists
    if ( empty( self::$number ) ) {

        // THIS IS ALWAYS STRING - WHY?
        $number = get_transient( 'my_number' );

        if ( false === $number && $post_id ) {
            $number = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_number', true );

            if ( '' !== $number ) {
                // THERE GOES AN ARRAY OF THE INTEGER
                set_transient('my_number', array( intval( $number ) ), 20 );
                self::$number = intval( $number );
                return intval( $number );
            }
        }

        self::$number = isset( $number[ 0 ] ) ? $number[ 0 ] : '';
    }

    return self::$number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transients are stored as options in the wp_options table (in most cases).

All option values are always converted to strings when stored. The table that holds them has the option_value column defined as longtext, and the option functions escape to string values when creating the SQL. Thus, bare integers will be converted to strings.

Since PHP is a loosely typed language, strings that are integers will be autoconverted when they are later used as integers, so this is not usually a problem.

Also note that any values which don't convert cleanly to string (like arrays, or objects) will be automatically serialized and unserialized when going to/from the database. The underlying WordPress option functions handle this for you, so it's not necessary to do it yourself. You can send an array or object to the transient functions and get the same thing back from them.

Post meta behaves in the same fashion, but in your code, when you get from the post_meta, you're running intval across the string, which is why you get back an integer.

Comment: Thank you, got it working by setting my integer in an array, as seen in my updated question.